# Yii2 не выводит ошибку валидации через ajax

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация

Здравствуйте, я новичок в Yii2 и в программирование тоже. Делаю форму регистрации, мне нужно выполнить проверку на уникальность email без перезагрузки страницы делаю так:
view:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'registration-form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email-pop-up">E-mail</label> 
        <?= $form->field($model_reg, 'email')->textInput()->label(false);  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password-pop-up-1">Пароль</label> 
        <?= yii\helpers\Html::activePasswordInput($model_reg, 'password', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password-pop-up-2">Повторить пароль</label>  
        <?= yii\helpers\Html::activePasswordInput($model_reg, 'password_repeat', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    </div>
```

Правила в модели:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['email',  'password', 'password_repeat'],'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass'=>'app\models\Person'], 
        ['password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password_repeat'],

    ];
}
```

Контроллер:

```
    $model_reg = new \app\models\Predreg();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model_reg->load(Yii::$app->request->post('Predreg'))) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;    
        return ActiveForm::validate($model_reg);
        Yii::$app->end();
    } 

    if (Yii::$app->request->post('Predreg')) {
        $model_reg->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('Predreg');
        if ($model_reg->validate()){
            if ($model_reg->predreg()){

               return \yii\helpers\Url::home();

            } 
        }
    }
```

Ошибка связанная с паролями работает верно, но не выводится ошибка неуникальности email адреса, если убираю свойство у формы 'enableAjaxValidation', то после перезагрузки страницы ошибка на месте.
Подскажите как вывести эту ошибку без перезагрузки страницы???

Comment: `if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model_reg->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {...}`

Comment: if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model_reg->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {...} если писать так, без указания к какой модели я обращаюсь, то POST запрос не проходит и возвращает ошибку 500

Comment: ну а в дебагере что?

Comment: в экшене у тебя return только если валидация успешна, соответсвенно ничего не возвращается, так-что ошибка 500 это уже шаг вперёд

Comment: нашел ошибку в дебагере, исправил, тем неменее проблема сохранилась, ошибка об неуникальности email не выводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На форуме yiiframework.ru подсказали, для того, чтобы ошибка отображалась нужно  в форме добавить validationUrl

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'registration-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validationUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['validate-form']), // Добавить URL валидации
]); ?>
```

а в контроллере добавить

```
public function actionValidateForm() 
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $model = new \app\models\Predreg();
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException('Bad request!');
}
```